# Uploading a mp4 to Google Cloud AutoML fails because it 'Failed to extract a thumbnail from the video'

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I'm trying to use AutoML Video Classification UI to train AutoML. I've been struggling with myriad errors... here is my latest: 'Failed to extract a thumbnail from the video.'

Sadly, the mp4 has a thumbnail... in fact I changed it via mp3Tag and re-uploaded and still receive the same error.

Here is the toplevel csv:

`UNASSIGNED,gs://mybucket_automl/classify_action.csv`

Here is the referencing classify_action.csv:

`gs://mybucket_automl/GH010056.MP4,,,`

and GH010056.MP4 is a valid MP4 with a cover thumbnail.

How do I fix this?

Note 1:  A smaller .mpg works.

Note 2: A smaller .mp4 fails same error.  Both files were 4K mp4s.

Note 3: A 1gb .mp4 of 1080p works.  Is this tied to the 4K? I haven't seen any docs that say I can't use 4K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug in how the error was handled but the general file requirements are no larger than 50 GB and no longer than 3 hours. Further, during the AutoML process, they will be downscaled to 1024x1024 so passing in 4K is probably causing the issue, as you discovered, assuming the other requirements were met. [[docs](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/object-tracking/docs/prepare#preparing_your_videos)]